# reinstalling mysql-client in ubuntu giving an error in openSIPS menuconfig tool

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, terminal, opensips

Initially my openSIPS server menuconfig tool worked properly

When I reinstalled mysql-client by ('sudo apt-get remove mysql-client' later install using 'sudo apt-get install mysql-client') the menuconfig tool of openSIPS gives some warning.

**You have enabled the 'db_mysql' module, so please install ' development librariePress any key to continue**

I tried by installing 'libmysqlclient-dev' but it didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

That warning is thrown regardless of your OS's libraries, so do not worry about it.

Indeed, it should be "please make sure XXX is installed". At least this sounds less severe. - I will patch it on the master branch.